# Are bindings needed on a mountain board?

Tags: injuries, skateboarding

Today, I decided to remove the Velcro bindings of my MBS Colt 95x for fear of causing an injury lest I fall but one foot doesn't come out of the bindings.

Is there any advantage to having Velcro bindings though?

Answer (score 1):

Certainly safety would be a consideration. Also it means your board won't go flying in the event that you do fall. If you fall off, your board would continue going down. If you fall with the Velcro then you keep the board with you like a snowboard.

Comment: A leash does solve that problem, though - a stretchy one so it doesn't catch on rocks etc